# nltk library is not running methods on JupyterLab

Tags: python, list, jupyter-notebook, nltk, jupyter-lab

I am trying to import nltk and use the method ".words" on JupyterLab. I had some difficulty trying to import the nltk library but I managed to download it using "nltk.download()". However, when I[no result shown on JupyterLab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDz0X.png) try to run the library and access the method, there is no list created.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a known error for some networks.

If you are using mobile hotspot **make sure your sim is not from Jio**.

> It seems to be that on some networks, I've been told "Jio" is one of them, raw.githubusercontent.com is not accessible, e.g.: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nltk/nltk_data/gh-pages/packages/tokenizers/punkt.xml